Boost kamada_kawai_spring_layout using Topology derived from GeographicLib ... failing
I am trying to get a kamada kawai spring layout to work on the surface of an ellipsoid.
I have written a convex_topology specialisation that implements GeographicLib's Geodesic functions, and then I applied a network (stored in json) along with initial positions (likewise stored).
However my code fails. I do not know if it's because the topology is badly defined, or if my implementation of Boost' kamada kawai layout is missing something it needs, or if I am just expecting way too much from everything.
The current topology is storing points as latitude/longitude doubles, and point_difference as a distance / bearing pair, with min/max using distance from the North Pole.  It may be better to use the xyz coordinates that Geodesic provides (surface on the ellipsoid, but when I tried that it failed also.
Here is the code I am using..
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <numbers>

#include <GeographicLib/Intersect.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Constants.hpp>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random_layout.hpp>

#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "rapidjson/ostreamwrapper.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace GeographicLib;

template <typename RandomNumberGenerator = minstd_rand > class geo_topology : public boost::convex_topology<2>
{
public:
    typedef typename convex_topology<2>::point_type point_type;
    typedef typename convex_topology<2>::point_difference_type point_difference_type;
    typedef boost::uniform_01< RandomNumberGenerator, double > rand_t;

private:
    shared_ptr< RandomNumberGenerator > gen_ptr;
    shared_ptr< rand_t > rand;
    Geodesic wgs84;

public:
    explicit geo_topology(Geodesic& g) : gen_ptr(new RandomNumberGenerator) , rand(new rand_t(*gen_ptr)),wgs84(g) {}
    geo_topology(RandomNumberGenerator& gen): gen_ptr(), rand(new rand_t(gen)),wgs84(Geodesic::WGS84()) {}
    
    point_type random_point() const {
        point_type p;
        p[0] = fmod((*rand)(),180.0) - 90.0;  // latitude.
        p[1] = fmod((*rand)(),360.0) - 180.0; // longitude.
        if (isnan(p[0]) or isnan(p[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in random_point" << std::endl;
        }
        return p;
    }

    point_type bound(point_type a) const {
        a[0] = fmod(a[0] + 90.0,180.0) - 90.0;   // latitude.
        a[1] = fmod(a[1] + 180.0,360.0) - 180.0; // longitude.
        if (isnan(a[0]) or isnan(a[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in bound" << std::endl;
        }
        return a;
    }

    double distance_from_boundary(point_type a) const {
        return 1000.0; // really don't know if this means anything.
    }

    point_type center() const {
        point_type result;
        result[0] = 90.0; // latitude.
        result[1] = 0.0;
        return result;
    }

    point_type origin() const {
        point_type result;
        result[0] = 0.0; // latitude.
        result[1] = 0.0;
        return result;
    }

    point_difference_type extent() const {
        point_difference_type result;
        result[0] = wgs84.EquatorialRadius(); // dist.
        result[1] = 360.0; // r_fwd_azi
        return result;
    }
        
    double distance(point a, point b) const {
        double dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        wgs84.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        if (isnan(dist)) {
            std::cerr << "dist shows nan distance" << std::endl;
        }
        return dist;
    }

    point move_position_toward(point a, double fraction, point b) const {
        point c;
        double dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        wgs84.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        GeodesicLine gl = wgs84.Line(a[0], a[1], r_fwd_azi);
        gl.Position(fraction * dist, c[0], c[1]);
        if (isnan(c[0]) or isnan(c[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in move_position_toward" << std::endl;
        }
        return c;
    }

    point_difference difference(point a, point b) const {  // a-b
        point_difference result;
        double r_rev_azi;
        wgs84.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], result[0], result[1], r_rev_azi);
        if (isnan(result[0]) or isnan(result[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in point_difference" << std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }

    point adjust(point a, point_difference delta) const {
        point result;  //point_difference = dist/fwd_azi
        if (isnan(delta[0]) or isnan(delta[1])) {
//          std::cerr << "nan in adjust.delta for point at " << a[0] << "," << a[1] << std::endl;
            point b = random_point();
            result = move_position_toward(a, 0.000001, b);
        } else {
            GeodesicLine gl = wgs84.Line(a[0], a[1], delta[1]);
            gl.Position(delta[0], result[0], result[1]);
            if (isnan(result[0]) or isnan(result[1])) {
                std::cerr << "nan in adjust" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    point pointwise_min(point a, point b) const {
        point result;
        double a_dist, b_dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        wgs84.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, a[0], a[1], a_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        wgs84.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, b[0], b[1], b_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        result = a_dist <= b_dist ? a : b;
        if (isnan(result[0]) or isnan(result[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in pointwise_min" << std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }

    point pointwise_max(point a, point b) const {
        point result;
        double a_dist, b_dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        wgs84.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, a[0], a[1], a_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        wgs84.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, b[0], b[1], b_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        result = a_dist >= b_dist ? a : b;
        if (isnan(result[0]) or isnan(result[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in pointwise_max" << std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }

    double norm(point_difference delta) const {
        return delta[0] / wgs84.EquatorialRadius();
    }

    double volume(point_difference delta) const {
        return delta[1];
    }

};

struct ExampleSpherical {
    
    static constexpr double r_mux = numbers::pi / 180.0;
    static constexpr double d_mux = 180.0 / numbers::pi;
    static constexpr double radius = 6371008.7714;
    static constexpr double q_circ = radius * numbers::pi * 0.5;

    using Topology           = geo_topology<>;
    using Point              = Topology::point_type;
    using EdgeWeightProperty = boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> ;

    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,                 //
                                        boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>,                  //
                                        boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int, EdgeWeightProperty> //
                                        >;
    size_t depth;
    double line_length;
    std::vector<unsigned long> vertices;
    using PosVector = std::vector<Point>;
    using vertex_id_t = unsigned long; //std::size_t;

    map<vertex_id_t,set<vertex_id_t>> net;
    map<vertex_id_t,Point> pos;
    Geodesic geo;
    Topology topo;

    ExampleSpherical(size_t d) : depth(d),geo(Geodesic::WGS84()),topo(geo) {
        line_length = q_circ / pow(3.0, double(depth+1));
    }
    
    void load_positions(const std::string filename) {
    //  Load latitude/longitude positions.
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        Document jpos;
        ifstream pos_file(filename);   // dict of node: pos
        string pos_str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(pos_file)),istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        jpos.Parse(pos_str.c_str());
        if (!jpos.HasParseError()) {
            auto n_end = jpos.MemberEnd();
            for (auto p_it = jpos.MemberBegin(); p_it != n_end; ++p_it) {
                unsigned long node = std::stoul (p_it->name.GetString());
                Point p;
                p[0] = p_it->value[0].GetDouble();
                p[1] = p_it->value[1].GetDouble();
                pos.insert({node,p});
            }
        }
        for (auto& a : pos) {
            for (auto & b : pos) {
                if (a.first != b.first) {
                    auto dx = topo.difference(a.second, b.second);
                    if (dx[0] < line_length) {
                        line_length = dx[0];
                    }
                    if (dx[0] < 0.000001) {
                        cout << "found overlapping nodes";
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Minimum Node Distance:" << line_length;
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        cout << "position load took: " << ms << "ms\n";
    }
    void load_network(const std::string filename) {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        Document jnet;
        ifstream net_file(filename); // dict with list "nodes" = each= eg {"id"=0}, and list links=eg {"source": 0, "target":2}
        string net_str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(net_file)),istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        jnet.Parse(net_str.c_str());
        if (!jnet.HasParseError()) {
            rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator n_ite = jnet["nodes"].Begin();
            rapidjson::Value::ConstValueIterator n_end = jnet["nodes"].End();
            do {
                net.insert({n_ite->GetObject()["id"].GetUint64(),{{},{}}});
                n_ite++;
            } while (n_ite != n_end);
            n_ite = jnet["links"].Begin();
            n_end = jnet["links"].End();
            do {
                unsigned long ia = n_ite->GetObject()["source"].GetUint64();
                unsigned long ib = n_ite->GetObject()["target"].GetUint64();
                net[ia].insert(ib);
                net[ib].insert(ia);
                n_ite++;
            } while (n_ite != n_end);
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        cout << "network load took: " << ms << "ms\n";
    }
    void validate_graph() {
        deque<vertex_id_t> dx;
        for (auto& node : net) {
            if (pos.find(node.first) == pos.end()) {
                dx.push_back(node.first);
            }
        }
        for (auto& node : net) {
            if (node.second.empty()) {
                dx.push_back(node.first);
            }
            for (auto& q : node.second ) {
                if (net.find(q) == net.end()) {
                    dx.push_back(node.first);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!dx.empty()) {
            cerr << "files did not reconcile correctly";
        }
    }
    void load_and_validate() {
        ostringstream graph_file_str;
        ostringstream graph_pos_str;
        graph_file_str << "graph_" << depth << ".json";
        graph_pos_str << "graph_ll_pos_"  << depth << ".json";
        load_network(graph_file_str.str());
        load_positions(graph_pos_str.str());
        validate_graph();
    }
    void save_positions(PosVector& final_pos) {
        ostringstream result_pos_str;
        result_pos_str << "result_ll_pos_"  << depth << ".json";
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        Document jpos;
        jpos.SetObject();
        auto& alloc = jpos.GetAllocator();
        for (auto& node: pos) {
            ostringstream os;
            os << node.first;
            string id = os.str();
            Value array(kArrayType);
            array.PushBack(final_pos[node.first][0],alloc);
            array.PushBack(final_pos[node.first][1],alloc);
            auto j_id = Value(id.c_str(), alloc);
            jpos.AddMember(j_id, array, alloc);
        }
        std::ofstream ofs { result_pos_str.str() };
        if ( !ofs.is_open() ) {
            std::cerr << "Could not open file for writing!\n";
        }
        OStreamWrapper osw { ofs };
        Writer<OStreamWrapper> writer2 { osw };
        jpos.Accept(writer2);
    
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        cout << "position save took: " << ms << "ms\n";
    }

    struct kamada_kawai_done {
        kamada_kawai_done() : last_delta() {}
        template<typename Graph>
        bool operator()(double delta_p,
                        typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor /*p*/,
                        const Graph& /*g*/,
                        bool global)
        {
            if (global) {
                double diff = last_delta - delta_p;
                if (diff < 0) diff = -diff;
                std::cout << "delta_p: " << delta_p << std::endl;
                last_delta = delta_p;
                return diff < 0.01;
            } else {
                return delta_p < 0.01;
            }
        }
        double last_delta;
    };
    
    void evaluate() {
        load_and_validate();
        vertices.resize(net.size());
        size_t i=0;
        for (auto n: net) {
            vertices[i] = n.first;
            i++;
        }
        Graph g(this->vertices.size());
        PosVector position(num_vertices(g));

        for (auto n: net) {
            auto& s = n.first;
            for (auto d: n.second) {
                if (d != s) {
                    add_edge(s, d, 1.0, g);
                } else {
                    cout << "Weird. source and destinations " << s << " and " << d << " are the same. Skipping that." << endl;
                }
            }
            position[s] = pos[s];
        }
        auto position_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(position.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));
        boost::kamada_kawai_spring_layout(g, position_map, get(boost::edge_weight, g), topo, boost::edge_length(10.0), kamada_kawai_done());
        save_positions(position);
    }
};

int main() {
    ExampleSpherical p(1);
    p.evaluate();
}

graph_0.json
{"directed": false, "multigraph": false, "graph": {}, "nodes": [{"id": 0}, {"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 6}, {"id": 7}, {"id": 8}, {"id": 9}, {"id": 10}, {"id": 11}, {"id": 12}, {"id": 13}, {"id": 14}, {"id": 15}, {"id": 16}, {"id": 17}, {"id": 18}, {"id": 19}, {"id": 20}, {"id": 21}, {"id": 22}, {"id": 23}, {"id": 24}, {"id": 25}, {"id": 26}, {"id": 27}, {"id": 28}, {"id": 29}, {"id": 30}, {"id": 31}, {"id": 32}, {"id": 33}, {"id": 34}, {"id": 35}, {"id": 36}, {"id": 37}], "links": [{"source": 0, "target": 2}, {"source": 0, "target": 1}, {"source": 0, "target": 4}, {"source": 0, "target": 3}, {"source": 1, "target": 7}, {"source": 1, "target": 3}, {"source": 1, "target": 5}, {"source": 1, "target": 2}, {"source": 1, "target": 6}, {"source": 2, "target": 4}, {"source": 2, "target": 8}, {"source": 2, "target": 5}, {"source": 2, "target": 10}, {"source": 3, "target": 9}, {"source": 3, "target": 11}, {"source": 3, "target": 6}, {"source": 3, "target": 4}, {"source": 4, "target": 9}, {"source": 4, "target": 8}, {"source": 4, "target": 12}, {"source": 5, "target": 7}, {"source": 5, "target": 14}, {"source": 5, "target": 16}, {"source": 5, "target": 10}, {"source": 6, "target": 15}, {"source": 6, "target": 17}, {"source": 6, "target": 11}, {"source": 6, "target": 7}, {"source": 7, "target": 15}, {"source": 7, "target": 13}, {"source": 7, "target": 14}, {"source": 8, "target": 10}, {"source": 8, "target": 20}, {"source": 8, "target": 12}, {"source": 8, "target": 22}, {"source": 9, "target": 21}, {"source": 9, "target": 12}, {"source": 9, "target": 11}, {"source": 9, "target": 23}, {"source": 10, "target": 20}, {"source": 10, "target": 16}, {"source": 10, "target": 18}, {"source": 11, "target": 17}, {"source": 11, "target": 19}, {"source": 11, "target": 21}, {"source": 12, "target": 22}, {"source": 12, "target": 24}, {"source": 12, "target": 23}, {"source": 13, "target": 14}, {"source": 13, "target": 25}, {"source": 13, "target": 15}, {"source": 14, "target": 28}, {"source": 14, "target": 16}, {"source": 14, "target": 25}, {"source": 15, "target": 25}, {"source": 15, "target": 29}, {"source": 15, "target": 17}, {"source": 16, "target": 26}, {"source": 16, "target": 28}, {"source": 16, "target": 18}, {"source": 17, "target": 27}, {"source": 17, "target": 29}, {"source": 17, "target": 19}, {"source": 18, "target": 26}, {"source": 18, "target": 20}, {"source": 19, "target": 27}, {"source": 19, "target": 21}, {"source": 20, "target": 26}, {"source": 20, "target": 22}, {"source": 20, "target": 31}, {"source": 21, "target": 32}, {"source": 21, "target": 23}, {"source": 21, "target": 27}, {"source": 22, "target": 30}, {"source": 22, "target": 31}, {"source": 22, "target": 24}, {"source": 23, "target": 24}, {"source": 23, "target": 30}, {"source": 23, "target": 32}, {"source": 24, "target": 30}, {"source": 25, "target": 28}, {"source": 25, "target": 29}, {"source": 25, "target": 33}, {"source": 26, "target": 34}, {"source": 26, "target": 31}, {"source": 26, "target": 28}, {"source": 27, "target": 29}, {"source": 27, "target": 35}, {"source": 27, "target": 32}, {"source": 28, "target": 33}, {"source": 28, "target": 34}, {"source": 29, "target": 33}, {"source": 29, "target": 35}, {"source": 30, "target": 32}, {"source": 30, "target": 36}, {"source": 30, "target": 31}, {"source": 31, "target": 36}, {"source": 31, "target": 34}, {"source": 32, "target": 35}, {"source": 32, "target": 36}, {"source": 33, "target": 37}, {"source": 33, "target": 35}, {"source": 33, "target": 34}, {"source": 34, "target": 37}, {"source": 34, "target": 36}, {"source": 35, "target": 37}, {"source": 35, "target": 36}, {"source": 36, "target": 37}]}

and graph_ll_0.json
{"0": [0.0, 180.0], "1": [0.0, -150.0], "2": [-30.000000000000004, 180.0], "3": [29.999999999999996, 180.0], "4": [0.0, 150.0], "5": [-35.264389682754654, -135.0], "6": [35.264389682754654, -135.0], "7": [0.0, -120.00000000000001], "8": [-35.264389682754654, 135.0], "9": [35.264389682754654, 135.0], "10": [-59.99999999999999, 180.0], "11": [59.99999999999999, 180.0], "12": [0.0, 120.00000000000001], "13": [0.0, -90.0], "14": [-29.999999999999996, -90.0], "15": [29.999999999999996, -90.0], "16": [-59.99999999999999, -90.0], "17": [59.99999999999999, -90.0], "18": [-90.0, 0.0], "19": [90.0, 0.0], "20": [-60.00000000000001, 90.0], "21": [60.00000000000001, 90.0], "22": [-30.000000000000004, 90.0], "23": [29.999999999999996, 90.0], "24": [0.0, 90.0], "25": [0.0, -60.00000000000001], "26": [-60.00000000000001, 0.0], "27": [60.00000000000001, 0.0], "28": [-35.264389682754654, -45.0], "29": [35.264389682754654, -45.0], "30": [0.0, 60.00000000000001], "31": [-35.264389682754654, 45.0], "32": [35.264389682754654, 45.0], "33": [0.0, -29.999999999999996], "34": [-30.000000000000004, 0.0], "35": [29.999999999999996, 0.0], "36": [0.0, 29.999999999999996], "37": [0.0, 0.0]}

Update
Sehe's contribution below resolved many bugs in my code - especially in relation to my poor understanding of boost's kamada_kawai_spring_layout
Topological 'norm' method should return the absolute of the point_difference (which is a {distance, bearing} couplet). The point_difference delta should not be arriving with a negative value, but it's happening somewhere inside kamada_kawai.
    double norm(point_difference delta) const {
        return abs(delta[0]);
    }

I am now seeing the spring values are distorting the positions more than the initial values (this is shown on a higher resolution of the network, but it makes no difference to the issue. Note that the rest of the vertices have not changed from the original:

This is what kamada_kawai should be looking somewhat like (though this was drawn fitting a unit sphere, rather than an ellipsoid, via using networkx on python - and, while networkx is good, it's too slow, memory hungry, and cannot support arbitrary topologies).

This shows the initial positions..

I am using a python script to convert the outputs to KMZ for visualisation..
import json
import simplekml
from utility.spherical import Spherical


def add_line(kz, pts, idx, name=None, col=(154, 154, 154), alpha=0.5, width=4):
    tpt = [pts[i] for i in idx]
    if len(tpt[0]) == 3:
        tpt = [sp.xyz_ll(tf) for tf in tpt]
    lo = [i[1] for i in tpt]
    mim = max(lo) - min(lo)
    if mim > 179.9999:
        path = [(o if o >= 0 else o + 360.0000, a) for (a, o) in tpt]
    else:
        path = [(o, a) for (a, o) in tpt]
    lstr = kz.newlinestring(name=name)
    lstr.coords = path
    lstr.style.linestyle.width = width


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sp = Spherical()
    for depth in [2]:
        pos_f = open(f'result_ll_pos_{depth}.json', 'r')
        pos_n = json.load(pos_f)
        pos_f.close()
        pos = dict()
        for k, v in pos_n.items():
            key = int(k)
            pos[key] = tuple(v)
        net_f = open(f'graph_{depth}.json', 'r')
        net = json.load(net_f)
        net_f.close()
        edges = net['links']
        kml = simplekml.Kml(open=1)
        for edge in edges:
            add_line(kml, pos, [edge['source'], edge['target']])
        kml.save(f'kkp_l_{depth}.kml')
        print(f'kml file generated {depth}')


It "fails"? I assume your example should be using depth=0 to match the inputs. The input should probably be graph_ll_pos_0.json instead of graph_ll_0.json. What is happening when you run that? What makes you say "it fails"?

Also, what is the question about. Is it about the projection/transformation or about the BGL algorithm. I have a feeling the whole question could  be presented without GeographicLib and RapidJson. Currently letting this run: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77a7a78893d585f0

This simplification at least fixes the bug in load_network https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3143c5b450000dd9 - so now "Weird. source and destinations 0 and 0 are the same. Skipping that." is no longer printed

I just spotted the update. As given abs(delta[0]) takes the integral part only. I have it like this: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a856053d6666471 - std::abs has overloads for real types

Hi there @sehe, great shout.  I realised that I should also probably be using a boost::numeric::ublas::vector (2) for the point_difference - and then write an instantiator from the magnitude and heading that GeographicLib returns with.

I'm sorry I couldn't help more with the topology side - geodesics are a bit above my pay-grade, I think. Also, I've previously seen "trouble" cases with kamada-kawai, but I can't find it again on this site. I think I was able to alleviate some of the symptoms, but it was with a regular topology back then.

@sehe, you did everything you needed to do.  I am all for learning - and this sort of stuff is completely new to me also.  I think that there might still be something wrong in the code, as it's very slow to converge. However - it is definitely working and I would not have got there without your help.

So after reviewing, I came up with a version that completes.
There was the bug that inserted 0 as a neighbour to any node (the initializer {{}, {}} creates set with the single element 0, because both {} value-initialze to that value).
Also, the network stores neighbours in both directions, but since the graph is undirected anyways, this results in all edges being duplicated. If this is not the intention, simply replace vecS with setS for the edges and the duplicates will auto-filter out.
Then, the edge index property is required, but wasn't populated correctly. They were all set to 1 (1.0, so it looks like that was /intended/ as the weight).
Neither was the weight. They were all defaulted to 0.
I think it's even better to not start with last_delta = 0.
Lastly, it's probably fine, but I wanted to make sure that the last_delta is actually retained, by passing the 'done' condition by reference.
Finally, I added a write_graphviz step to render the input as parsed for inspection:
Live On Coliru
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/ostreamwrapper.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include <GeographicLib/Constants.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Intersect.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random_layout.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

namespace GL = GeographicLib;

template <typename RandomNumberGenerator = std::minstd_rand>
class geo_topology : public boost::convex_topology<2> {
  public:
    using point_type            = typename convex_topology<2>::point_type;
    using point_difference_type = typename convex_topology<2>::point_difference_type;
    using rand_t                = boost::uniform_01<RandomNumberGenerator, double>;

  private:
    RandomNumberGenerator gen_;
    mutable rand_t        rand_{gen_};
    GL::Geodesic          geodesic_;

  public:
    geo_topology(geo_topology const&)            = delete;
    geo_topology& operator=(geo_topology const&) = delete;

    explicit geo_topology(GL::Geodesic const& g) : geodesic_(g) {}
    geo_topology(RandomNumberGenerator gen) : gen_(std::move(gen)), geodesic_(GL::Geodesic::WGS84()) {}

    point_type random_point() const {
        point_type p;
        p[0] = fmod(rand_(), 180.0) - 90.0;  // latitude.
        p[1] = fmod(rand_(), 360.0) - 180.0; // longitude.
        if (std::isnan(p[0]) or std::isnan(p[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in random_point" << std::endl;
        }
        return p;
    }

    point_type bound(point_type a) const {
        a[0] = fmod(a[0] + 90.0, 180.0) - 90.0;   // latitude.
        a[1] = fmod(a[1] + 180.0, 360.0) - 180.0; // longitude.
        if (std::isnan(a[0]) or std::isnan(a[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in bound" << std::endl;
        }
        return a;
    }

    double distance_from_boundary(point_type /*a*/) const {
        return 1000.0; // really don't know if this means anything.
    }

    point_type center() const {
        point_type result;
        result[0] = 90.0; // latitude.
        result[1] = 0.0;
        return result;
    }

    point_type origin() const {
        point_type result;
        result[0] = 0.0; // latitude.
        result[1] = 0.0;
        return result;
    }

    point_difference_type extent() const {
        point_difference_type result;
        result[0] = geodesic_.EquatorialRadius(); // dist.
        result[1] = 360.0;                        // r_fwd_azi
        return result;
    }

    double distance(point a, point b) const {
        double dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        if (std::isnan(dist)) {
            std::cerr << "dist shows nan distance" << std::endl;
        }
        return dist;
    }

    point move_position_toward(point a, double fraction, point b) const {
        point  c;
        double dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        GL::GeodesicLine gl = geodesic_.Line(a[0], a[1], r_fwd_azi);
        gl.Position(fraction * dist, c[0], c[1]);
        if (std::isnan(c[0]) or std::isnan(c[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in move_position_toward" << std::endl;
        }
        return c;
    }

    point_difference difference(point a, point b) const { // a-b
        point_difference result;
        double           r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], result[0], result[1], r_rev_azi);
        if (std::isnan(result[0]) or std::isnan(result[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in point_difference" << std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }

    point adjust(point a, point_difference delta) const {
        point result; // point_difference = dist/fwd_azi
        if (std::isnan(delta[0]) or std::isnan(delta[1])) {
            //          std::cerr << "nan in adjust.delta for point at " << a[0] << "," << a[1] << std::endl;
            point b = random_point();
            result  = move_position_toward(a, 0.000001, b);
        } else {
            GL::GeodesicLine gl = geodesic_.Line(a[0], a[1], delta[1]);
            gl.Position(delta[0], result[0], result[1]);
            if (std::isnan(result[0]) or std::isnan(result[1])) {
                std::cerr << "nan in adjust" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    point pointwise_min(point a, point b) const {
        point  result;
        double a_dist, b_dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, a[0], a[1], a_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        geodesic_.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, b[0], b[1], b_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        result = a_dist <= b_dist ? a : b;
        if (std::isnan(result[0]) or std::isnan(result[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in pointwise_min" << std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }

    point pointwise_max(point a, point b) const {
        point  result;
        double a_dist, b_dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, a[0], a[1], a_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        geodesic_.Inverse(90.0, 0.0, b[0], b[1], b_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        result = a_dist >= b_dist ? a : b;
        if (std::isnan(result[0]) or std::isnan(result[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in pointwise_max" << std::endl;
        }
        return result;
    }

    double norm(point_difference delta) const { return delta[0] / geodesic_.EquatorialRadius(); }

    double volume(point_difference delta) const { return delta[1]; }
};

namespace boost {
    // for graphviz output of node position
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, geo_topology<>::point const& p) { return os << "(" << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << ")"; }
    static std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, geo_topology<>::point&) { is.setstate(std::ios::failbit); return is; } // NOT IMPLEMENTED
} // namespace boost

struct ExampleSpherical {

    static constexpr double r_mux  = std::numbers::pi / 180.0;
    static constexpr double d_mux  = 180.0 / std::numbers::pi;
    static constexpr double radius = 6371008.7714;
    static constexpr double q_circ = radius * std::numbers::pi * 0.5;

    using Topology           = geo_topology<>;
    using Point              = Topology::point_type;
    using EdgeWeightProperty = boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>;

    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
                                        boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int, EdgeWeightProperty>>;
    using V = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
    using E = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

    size_t const depth;
    double       line_length;
    using PosVector   = std::vector<Point>;
    using vertex_id_t = unsigned long; // std::size_t;

    std::map<vertex_id_t, std::set<vertex_id_t>> network_;
    std::map<vertex_id_t, Point>                 initial_positions_;
    GL::Geodesic                                 geo;
    Topology                                     topo;

    ExampleSpherical(size_t d) : depth(d), geo(GL::Geodesic::WGS84()), topo(geo) {
        line_length = q_circ / pow(3.0, double(depth + 1));
        std::cout << "depth:" << depth << " line_length:" << line_length << std::endl;
    }

    void load_positions(std::string const filename) {
        //  Load latitude/longitude positions.
        auto                start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        rapidjson::Document jpos;
        std::ifstream       pos_file(filename); // dict of node: pos
        std::string         pos_str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(pos_file), {});
        jpos.Parse(pos_str.c_str());
        if (!jpos.HasParseError()) {
            for (auto p_it = jpos.MemberBegin(), n_end = jpos.MemberEnd(); p_it != n_end; ++p_it) {
                auto  node = std::stoul(p_it->name.GetString());
                Point p;
                p[0] = p_it->value[0].GetDouble();
                p[1] = p_it->value[1].GetDouble();
                initial_positions_.emplace(node, std::move(p));
            }
        }
        for (auto& [a_id, a_pos] : initial_positions_) {
            for (auto& [b_id, b_pos] : initial_positions_) {
                if (a_id != b_id) {
                    auto dx = topo.difference(a_pos, b_pos);
                    if (dx[0] < line_length) {
                        line_length = dx[0];
                    }
                    if (dx[0] < 0.000001) {
                        std::cout << "found overlapping nodes" << std::endl;
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Minimum Node Distance:" << line_length << std::endl;
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        std::cout << "position load took: " << ms << "ms" << std::endl;
    }

    void load_network(std::string const filename) {
        auto                start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        rapidjson::Document jnet;
        std::ifstream net_file(filename); // dict with list "nodes" = each= eg {"id"=0}, and list links=eg
                                          // {"source": 0, "target":2}
        std::string net_str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(net_file), {});
        jnet.Parse(net_str.c_str());
        if (!jnet.HasParseError()) {
            for (auto&& n : jnet["nodes"].GetArray())
                network_.insert({n.GetObject()["id"].GetUint64(), {}});

            for (auto&& l : jnet["links"].GetArray()) {
                auto ia = l.GetObject()["source"].GetUint64();
                auto ib = l.GetObject()["target"].GetUint64();
                network_[ia].insert(ib);
                network_[ib].insert(ia);
            }
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        std::cout << "network load took: " << ms << "ms\n";
    }

    void validate_graph() const {
        assert(network_.size() == initial_positions_.size());

        std::set<vertex_id_t> error_nodes;
        for (auto& [id, dd] : network_) {
            if (!initial_positions_.contains(id))
                error_nodes.insert(id); // no position
            if (dd.empty())    // no edges
                error_nodes.insert(id);
            for (auto& q : dd)
                if (!network_.contains(q)) // missing neighbour
                    error_nodes.insert(id);
        }

        if (!error_nodes.empty())
            throw std::runtime_error("files did not reconcile correctly");
    }

    void load_and_validate() {
        load_network("graph_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".json");
        load_positions("graph_ll_pos_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".json");
        validate_graph();
    }

    void save_positions(PosVector& final_pos) const {
        auto                start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        rapidjson::Document jpos;
        jpos.SetObject();
        auto& alloc = jpos.GetAllocator();
        for (auto& [id, _] : initial_positions_) {
            rapidjson::Value array(rapidjson::kArrayType);
            array.PushBack(final_pos[id][0], alloc);
            array.PushBack(final_pos[id][1], alloc);
            auto j_id = rapidjson::Value(std::to_string(id).c_str(), alloc);
            jpos.AddMember(j_id, array, alloc);
        }
        std::ofstream ofs{"result_ll_pos_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".json"};
        if (!ofs.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Could not open file for writing!\n";
        }
        rapidjson::OStreamWrapper                    osw{ofs};
        rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::OStreamWrapper> writer2{osw};
        jpos.Accept(writer2);

        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        std::cout << "position save took: " << ms << "ms\n";
    }

    struct kamada_kawai_done {
        bool operator()(double delta_p, V /*p*/, Graph const& /*g*/, bool global) {
            std::cout << "kamada_kawai_done " << (global ? "(global) " : "") << delta_p << std::endl;
            if (global) {
                using std::abs;
                auto diff = abs(last_delta - delta_p);
                std::cout << "delta_p: " << delta_p << " diff: " << diff << std::endl;
                last_delta = delta_p;
                return diff < 0.01;
            } else {
                return delta_p < 0.01;
            }
        }
        double last_delta = 0;
    };

    void evaluate() const {
        // std::vector<unsigned long> vertices_(network_.size());
        // for (auto [id, _] : network_)
        //     vertices_.push_back(id);

        Graph     g(network_.size());
        PosVector position(num_vertices(g));
        auto      wmap = get(boost::edge_weight, g);
        auto      eidx = get(boost::edge_index, g);

        for (size_t edge_idx = 0; auto [s, dd] : network_) {
            for (auto d : dd) {
                assert(d != s);
                assert(d < num_vertices(g));
                assert(s < num_vertices(g));
                auto [e, not_duplicate] = add_edge(s, d, g);

                if (not_duplicate) {
                    eidx[e] = edge_idx++; // required to map edges to [0, num_edges(g))
                    wmap[e] = 1.0;        // weight bust all be non-negative
                }
            }
            position[s] = initial_positions_.at(s); // throws if not found.
        }
        auto position_map = make_iterator_property_map(position.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

        {
            // save graph-viz
            boost::dynamic_properties dp;
            dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, g));
            dp.property("pos", position_map);
            dp.property("edge_id", eidx);
            dp.property("weight", wmap);

            std::ofstream dot("graph_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".dot");
            write_graphviz_dp(dot, g, dp);
            // create PNG:
            ::system(("dot -Tpng 'graph_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".dot' -o 'graph_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".png'").c_str());
        }

        kamada_kawai_done condition{line_length / 2.0};
        kamada_kawai_spring_layout(g, position_map, wmap, topo, boost::edge_length(10.0),
                                   std::ref(condition));
        save_positions(position);
    }
};

int main() {
    ExampleSpherical p(0);
    p.load_and_validate();
    p.evaluate();
}

This prints e.g.:
depth:0 line_length:3.33585e+06
network load took: 2ms
Minimum Node Distance:3.32011e+06
position load took: 1ms
kamada_kawai_done (global) 0
delta_p: 0 diff: 1.66006e+06
kamada_kawai_done -141.912
kamada_kawai_done (global) -141.9
delta_p: -141.9 diff: 141.9
kamada_kawai_done -141.9
kamada_kawai_done (global) -141.9
delta_p: -141.9 diff: 0
position save took: 0ms

The dot graph:
graph G {
0  [pos="(0,        180)"];  1  [pos="(0,        -150)"]; 2  [pos="(-30,     180)"];  3    [pos="(30,       180)"];    4  [pos="(0,       150)"];
5  [pos="(-35.2644, -135)"]; 6  [pos="(35.2644,  -135)"]; 7  [pos="(0,       -120)"]; 8    [pos="(-35.2644, 135)"];    9  [pos="(35.2644, 135)"];
10 [pos="(-60,      180)"];  11 [pos="(60,       180)"];  12 [pos="(0,       120)"];  13   [pos="(0,        -90)"];    14 [pos="(-30,     -90)"];
15 [pos="(30,       -90)"];  16 [pos="(-60,      -90)"];  17 [pos="(60,      -90)"];  18   [pos="(-90,      0)"];      19 [pos="(90,      0)"];
20 [pos="(-60,      90)"];   21 [pos="(60,       90)"];   22 [pos="(-30,     90)"];   23   [pos="(30,       90)"];     24 [pos="(0,       90)"];
25 [pos="(0,        -60)"];  26 [pos="(-60,      0)"];    27 [pos="(60,      0)"];    28   [pos="(-35.2644, -45)"];    29 [pos="(35.2644, -45)"];
30 [pos="(0,        60)"];   31 [pos="(-35.2644, 45)"];   32 [pos="(35.2644, 45)"];   33   [pos="(0,        -30)"];    34 [pos="(-30,     0)"];
35 [pos="(30,       0)"];    36 [pos="(0,        30)"];   37 [pos="(0,       0)"];    0--1 [edge_id=4,      weight=1];
0--2  [edge_id=10, weight=1];     0--3  [edge_id=16, weight=1];     0--4  [edge_id=22, weight=1];     1--2  [edge_id=11, weight=1];     1--3  [edge_id=17, weight=1];
1--5  [edge_id=28, weight=1];     1--6  [edge_id=34, weight=1];     1--7  [edge_id=40, weight=1];     2--4  [edge_id=23, weight=1];     2--5  [edge_id=29, weight=1];
2--8  [edge_id=46, weight=1];     2--10  [edge_id=58, weight=1];    3--4  [edge_id=24, weight=1];     3--6  [edge_id=35, weight=1];     3--9  [edge_id=52, weight=1];
3--11  [edge_id=64, weight=1];    4--8  [edge_id=47, weight=1];     4--9  [edge_id=53, weight=1];     4--12  [edge_id=70, weight=1];    5--7  [edge_id=41, weight=1];
5--10  [edge_id=59, weight=1];    5--14  [edge_id=80, weight=1];    5--16  [edge_id=92, weight=1];    6--7  [edge_id=42, weight=1];     6--11  [edge_id=65, weight=1];
6--15  [edge_id=86, weight=1];    6--17  [edge_id=98, weight=1];    7--13  [edge_id=76, weight=1];    7--14  [edge_id=81, weight=1];    7--15  [edge_id=87, weight=1];
8--10  [edge_id=60, weight=1];    8--12  [edge_id=71, weight=1];    8--20  [edge_id=112, weight=1];   8--22  [edge_id=124, weight=1];   9--11  [edge_id=66, weight=1];
9--12  [edge_id=72, weight=1];    9--21  [edge_id=118, weight=1];   9--23  [edge_id=130, weight=1];   10--16  [edge_id=93, weight=1];   10--18  [edge_id=104, weight=1];
10--20  [edge_id=113, weight=1];  11--17  [edge_id=99, weight=1];   11--19  [edge_id=108, weight=1];  11--21  [edge_id=119, weight=1];  12--22  [edge_id=125, weight=1];
12--23  [edge_id=131, weight=1];  12--24  [edge_id=136, weight=1];  13--14  [edge_id=82, weight=1];   13--15  [edge_id=88, weight=1];   13--25  [edge_id=140, weight=1];
14--16  [edge_id=94, weight=1];   14--25  [edge_id=141, weight=1];  14--28  [edge_id=158, weight=1];  15--17  [edge_id=100, weight=1];  15--25  [edge_id=142, weight=1];
15--29  [edge_id=164, weight=1];  16--18  [edge_id=105, weight=1];  16--26  [edge_id=146, weight=1];  16--28  [edge_id=159, weight=1];  17--19  [edge_id=109, weight=1];
17--27  [edge_id=152, weight=1];  17--29  [edge_id=165, weight=1];  18--20  [edge_id=114, weight=1];  18--26  [edge_id=147, weight=1];  19--21  [edge_id=120, weight=1];
19--27  [edge_id=153, weight=1];  20--22  [edge_id=126, weight=1];  20--26  [edge_id=148, weight=1];  20--31  [edge_id=176, weight=1];  21--23  [edge_id=132, weight=1];
21--27  [edge_id=154, weight=1];  21--32  [edge_id=182, weight=1];  22--24  [edge_id=137, weight=1];  22--30  [edge_id=170, weight=1];  22--31  [edge_id=177, weight=1];
23--24  [edge_id=138, weight=1];  23--30  [edge_id=171, weight=1];  23--32  [edge_id=183, weight=1];  24--30  [edge_id=172, weight=1];  25--28  [edge_id=160, weight=1];
25--29  [edge_id=166, weight=1];  25--33  [edge_id=188, weight=1];  26--28  [edge_id=161, weight=1];  26--31  [edge_id=178, weight=1];  26--34  [edge_id=194, weight=1];
27--29  [edge_id=167, weight=1];  27--32  [edge_id=184, weight=1];  27--35  [edge_id=200, weight=1];  28--33  [edge_id=189, weight=1];  28--34  [edge_id=195, weight=1];
29--33  [edge_id=190, weight=1];  29--35  [edge_id=201, weight=1];  30--31  [edge_id=179, weight=1];  30--32  [edge_id=185, weight=1];  30--36  [edge_id=206, weight=1];
31--34  [edge_id=196, weight=1];  31--36  [edge_id=207, weight=1];  32--35  [edge_id=202, weight=1];  32--36  [edge_id=208, weight=1];  33--34  [edge_id=197, weight=1];
33--35  [edge_id=203, weight=1];  33--37  [edge_id=212, weight=1];  34--36  [edge_id=209, weight=1];  34--37  [edge_id=213, weight=1];  35--36  [edge_id=210, weight=1];
35--37  [edge_id=214, weight=1];  36--37  [edge_id=215, weight=1];
}


The resulting result_ll_pos_0.json:
{
    "0": [1.3505670147100813e-12, 180.0],
    "1": [0.0, -150.0],
    "2": [-30.000000000000004, 180.0],
    "3": [29.999999999999996, 180.0],
    "4": [0.0, 150.0],
    "5": [-35.264389682754654, -135.0],
    "6": [35.264389682754654, -135.0],
    "7": [0.0, -120.0],
    "8": [-35.264389682754654, 135.0],
    "9": [35.264389682754654, 135.0],
    "10": [-59.99999999999999, 180.0],
    "11": [59.99999999999999, 180.0],
    "12": [0.0, 120.0],
    "13": [0.0, -90.0],
    "14": [-29.999999999999996, -90.0],
    "15": [29.999999999999996, -90.0],
    "16": [-59.99999999999999, -90.0],
    "17": [59.99999999999999, -90.0],
    "18": [-89.99999999999866, -0.0006610126423928427],
    "19": [90.0, 0.0],
    "20": [-60.00000000000001, 90.0],
    "21": [60.00000000000001, 90.0],
    "22": [-30.000000000000004, 90.0],
    "23": [29.999999999999996, 90.0],
    "24": [0.0, 90.0],
    "25": [0.0, -60.00000000000001],
    "26": [-60.00000000000001, 0.0],
    "27": [60.00000000000001, 0.0],
    "28": [-35.264389682754654, -45.0],
    "29": [35.264389682754654, -45.0],
    "30": [0.0, 60.00000000000001],
    "31": [-35.264389682754654, 45.0],
    "32": [35.264389682754654, 45.0],
    "33": [0.0, -29.999999999999996],
    "34": [-30.000000000000004, 0.0],
    "35": [29.999999999999996, 0.0],
    "36": [0.0, 29.999999999999996],
    "37": [0.0, 0.0]
}


Interestingly, even with the added validations and the generating of the graphviz+PNG render, my reviewed copy became about 13 lines shorter. I hope you will review the many other common-practice changes. And thanks for getting me look into the std::numbers namespace!

PS.: I did not look much at the topology calculations. I have a suspicion that these were not the biggest issue.

Absolutely awesome work, @sehe.  I realise that I was adding more bugs into my code trying to find out where the issue was.  Your experience and understanding of this was invaluable.  I noticed that the topological norm() function was returning negative values, and using an abs() there - along with all your stellar (and far more significant) changes - helped the algorithm to run for more than one iteration - but despite the herculean work you have done on my code the algorithm does not seem to be working correctly still - the nodes are moving way too much, which is weird.

I could not have got here without the help of @sehe.
As mentioned in the comments, I needed to author a suitable point_difference struct, and then I also noticed that I was not switching between radians (boost, C++ maths) and degrees (GeographicLib) correctly.  After that, I suspected that, for some reason, the delta being passed by kamada_kawai_spring_layout to adjust() the positions needs inverting (or I don't understand the intention the call(!) so I added pi/180° to the value it sends.
While there are still things here which could be optimised out (as well as several superfluous functions), the working code is as follows.
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/ostreamwrapper.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include <GeographicLib/Constants.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>
#include <GeographicLib/Intersect.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random_layout.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector_expression.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <numbers>


static constexpr double r_mux  = std::numbers::pi / 180.0;
static constexpr double d_mux  = 180.0 / std::numbers::pi;

namespace GL = GeographicLib;

template <typename RandomNumberGenerator = std::minstd_rand>
class geo_topology : public boost::convex_topology<2> {
  public:
    using point_type            = typename convex_topology<2>::point_type;
    using rand_t                = boost::uniform_01<RandomNumberGenerator, double>;
    using geo_vec               = boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double>;

  private:
    RandomNumberGenerator gen_;
    mutable rand_t        rand_{gen_};
    GL::Geodesic          geodesic_;

  public:
    geo_topology(geo_topology const&)            = delete;
    geo_topology& operator=(geo_topology const&) = delete;

    explicit geo_topology(GL::Geodesic const& g) : geodesic_(g) {}
    geo_topology(RandomNumberGenerator gen) : gen_(std::move(gen)), geodesic_(GL::Geodesic::WGS84()) {}

    public:
        struct pt_difference {
        private:
            geo_vec v;
        public:
            pt_difference() : v(2) {v[0] = 0.0; v[1] = 0.0;}
            double& operator[](std::size_t i) { return v[i]; }
            const double& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return v[i]; }
                        
            pt_difference(double mag, double heading) : v(2) {
                v[0] = cos(heading) * mag; v[1] = sin(heading) * mag;
            }
            
            double magnitude() const {
                return boost::numeric::ublas::norm_2(v);
            }
            
            double heading() const {
                return atan2(v[1], v[0]);
            }

            friend pt_difference operator+(
                const pt_difference& a, const pt_difference& b) {
                return a.v+b.v;
            }

            friend pt_difference& operator+=(pt_difference& a, const pt_difference& b) {
                a.v = a.v += b.v;
                return a;
            }

            friend pt_difference operator-(const pt_difference& a) {
                pt_difference r;
                return r - a;
            }

            friend pt_difference operator-(const pt_difference& a, const pt_difference& b) {
                pt_difference r;
                r.v = a.v - b.v;
                return r;
            }

            friend pt_difference& operator-=(pt_difference& a, const pt_difference& b) {
                a.v-=b.v;
                return a;
            }

            friend pt_difference operator*(
                const pt_difference& a, const pt_difference& b) {
                return a.v*b.v;
            }

            friend pt_difference operator*(const pt_difference& a, double b) {
                throw std::runtime_error("vector * double");
                return a;
            }

            friend pt_difference operator*(double a, const pt_difference& b){
                double m = b.magnitude() * a;
                double d = b.heading();
                return pt_difference(m, d);
            }

            friend pt_difference operator/(
                const pt_difference& a, const pt_difference& b) {
                return a.v / b.v;
            }

            friend double dot(const pt_difference& a, const pt_difference& b) {
                return boost::numeric::ublas::inner_prod(a.v, b.v);
            }
            
        };

    using point_difference_type = typename geo_topology::pt_difference;

    
    point_type random_point() const {
        throw std::runtime_error("random_point used.");
        point_type p;
        p[0] = fmod(rand_(), std::numbers::pi) - 0.5*std::numbers::pi;  // latitude.
        p[1] = fmod(rand_(), 2.0*std::numbers::pi) - std::numbers::pi; // longitude.
        if (std::isnan(p[0]) or std::isnan(p[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in random_point" << std::endl;
        }
        return p;
    }

    point_type bound(point_type a) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("bound used.");
        a[0] = fmod(a[0] + 0.5*std::numbers::pi, std::numbers::pi) - 0.5*std::numbers::pi;   // latitude.
        a[1] = fmod(a[1] + std::numbers::pi, 2.0*std::numbers::pi) - std::numbers::pi; // longitude.
        if (std::isnan(a[0]) or std::isnan(a[1])) {
            std::cerr << "nan in bound" << std::endl;
        }
        return a;
    }

    double distance_from_boundary(point_type /*a*/) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("distance_from_boundary used.");
        return 1000.0; // really don't know if this means anything.
    }

    point_type center() const {
        throw std::runtime_error("center used.");
        point_type result;
        result[0] = std::numbers::pi * 0.5; // latitude.
        result[1] = 0.0;
        return result;
    }

    point_type origin() const {
        throw std::runtime_error("origin used.");
        point_type result;
        result[0] = 0.0; // latitude.
        result[1] = 0.0;
        return result;
    }

    pt_difference extent() const {
        throw std::runtime_error("extent used.");
        return pt_difference(geodesic_.EquatorialRadius(), 2 * std::numbers::pi);
    }

    double distance(point a, point b) const {
        double dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        return dist;
    }

    point move_position_toward(point a, double fraction, point b) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("move_position_toward used.");
        point  c;
        double dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        GL::GeodesicLine gl = geodesic_.Line(a[0], a[1], r_fwd_azi);
        gl.Position(fraction * dist, c[0], c[1]);
        return c;
    }

    pt_difference difference(point a, point b) const { // a-b
        double           r_rev_azi;
        double           mag,heading;
        geodesic_.Inverse(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1], mag, heading, r_rev_azi);
        return pt_difference(mag, r_mux * heading);
    }

    point adjust(point a, pt_difference delta) const {
        point result(a); // point_difference = dist/fwd_azi
        double mag = delta.magnitude();
        double dir = delta.heading() + std::numbers::pi;
        GL::GeodesicLine gl = geodesic_.Line(a[0], a[1], d_mux * dir);
        gl.Position(mag, result[0], result[1]);
        return result;
    }

    point pointwise_min(point a, point b) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("pointwise_min used.");
        point  result;
        double a_dist, b_dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(0.5 * std::numbers::pi, 0.0, a[0], a[1], a_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        geodesic_.Inverse(0.5 * std::numbers::pi, 0.0, b[0], b[1], b_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        result = a_dist <= b_dist ? a : b;
        return result;
    }

    point pointwise_max(point a, point b) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("pointwise_max used.");
        point  result;
        double a_dist, b_dist = 0.0;
        double r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi;
        geodesic_.Inverse(0.5 * std::numbers::pi, 0.0, a[0], a[1], a_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        geodesic_.Inverse(0.5 * std::numbers::pi, 0.0, b[0], b[1], b_dist, r_fwd_azi, r_rev_azi);
        result = a_dist >= b_dist ? a : b;
        return result;
    }

    double norm(pt_difference delta) const {
        return delta.magnitude();
    }

    double volume(pt_difference delta) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("volume used.");
        return delta[1];
    }
};

namespace boost {
    // for graphviz output of node position
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, geo_topology<>::point const& p) { return os << "(" << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << ")"; }
    static std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, geo_topology<>::point&) { is.setstate(std::ios::failbit); return is; } // NOT IMPLEMENTED
} // namespace boost

struct ExampleSpherical {

    static constexpr double radius = 6371008.7714;
    static constexpr double q_circ = radius * std::numbers::pi * 0.5;

    using Topology           = geo_topology<>;
    using Point              = Topology::point_type;
    using EdgeWeightProperty = boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>;

    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property,
                                        boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int, EdgeWeightProperty>>;
    using V = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
    using E = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;

    size_t const depth;
    double       line_length;
    using PosVector   = std::vector<Point>;
    using vertex_id_t = unsigned long; // std::size_t;

    std::map<vertex_id_t, std::set<vertex_id_t>> network_;
    std::map<vertex_id_t, Point>                 initial_positions_;
    GL::Geodesic                                 geo;
    Topology                                     topo;

    ExampleSpherical(size_t d) : depth(d), geo(GL::Geodesic::WGS84()), topo(geo) {
        line_length = q_circ / pow(3.0, double(depth + 1));
    }

    void load_positions(std::string const filename) {
        //  Load latitude/longitude positions.
        auto                start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        rapidjson::Document jpos;
        std::ifstream       pos_file(filename); // dict of node: pos
        std::string         pos_str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(pos_file), {});
        jpos.Parse(pos_str.c_str());
        if (!jpos.HasParseError()) {
            for (auto p_it = jpos.MemberBegin(), n_end = jpos.MemberEnd(); p_it != n_end; ++p_it) {
                auto  node = std::stoul(p_it->name.GetString());
                Point p;
                p[0] = p_it->value[0].GetDouble();
                p[1] = p_it->value[1].GetDouble();
                initial_positions_.emplace(node, std::move(p));
            }
        }
        for (auto& [a_id, a_pos] : initial_positions_) {
            for (auto& [b_id, b_pos] : initial_positions_) {
                if (a_id != b_id) {
                    double mag = topo.difference(a_pos, b_pos).magnitude();
                    if (mag < 0.01) {
                        std::cout << "found overlapping nodes " << a_pos << " " << b_pos << std::endl;
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Optimal Node Distance:" << line_length << std::endl;
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        std::cout << "position load took: " << ms << "ms" << std::endl;
    }

    void load_network(std::string const filename) {
        auto                start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        rapidjson::Document jnet;
        std::ifstream net_file(filename); // dict with list "nodes" = each= eg {"id"=0}, and list links=eg
                                          // {"source": 0, "target":2}
        std::string net_str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(net_file), {});
        jnet.Parse(net_str.c_str());
        if (!jnet.HasParseError()) {
            for (auto&& n : jnet["nodes"].GetArray())
                network_.insert({n.GetObject()["id"].GetUint64(), {}});

            for (auto&& l : jnet["links"].GetArray()) {
                auto ia = l.GetObject()["source"].GetUint64();
                auto ib = l.GetObject()["target"].GetUint64();
                network_[ia].insert(ib);
                network_[ib].insert(ia);
            }
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        std::cout << "network load took: " << ms << "ms\n";
    }

    void validate_graph() const {
        assert(network_.size() == initial_positions_.size());

        std::set<vertex_id_t> error_nodes;
        for (auto& [id, dd] : network_) {
            if (!initial_positions_.contains(id))
                error_nodes.insert(id); // no position
            if (dd.empty())    // no edges
                error_nodes.insert(id);
            for (auto& q : dd)
                if (!network_.contains(q)) // missing neighbour
                    error_nodes.insert(id);
        }

        if (!error_nodes.empty())
            throw std::runtime_error("files did not reconcile correctly");
    }

    void load_and_validate() {
        load_network("graph_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".json");
        load_positions("graph_ll_pos_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".json");
        validate_graph();
    }

    void save_positions(PosVector& final_pos) const {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        rapidjson::Document jpos;
        jpos.SetObject();
        auto& alloc = jpos.GetAllocator();
        for (auto& [id, _] : initial_positions_) {
            rapidjson::Value array(rapidjson::kArrayType);
            array.PushBack(final_pos[id][0], alloc);
            array.PushBack(final_pos[id][1], alloc);
            auto j_id = rapidjson::Value(std::to_string(id).c_str(), alloc);
            jpos.AddMember(j_id, array, alloc);
        }
        std::ofstream ofs{"result_ll_pos_" + std::to_string(depth) + ".json"};
        if (!ofs.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Could not open file for writing!\n";
        }
        rapidjson::OStreamWrapper                    osw{ofs};
        rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::OStreamWrapper> writer2{osw};
        jpos.Accept(writer2);

        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto ms  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        std::cout << "position save took: " << ms << "ms\n";
    }

    struct kamada_kawai_done {

        bool operator()(double delta_p, V /*p*/, Graph const& /*g*/, bool global) {
            counter--;
            if (global) {
                auto diff = fabs(last_delta - delta_p);
                std::cout << counter << "; delta_p: " << delta_p << " diff: " << diff << std::endl;
                last_delta = delta_p;
                return fabs(diff) < 0.01 or counter < 1;
            } else {
                if (counter % 100 == 0) {
                    std::cout << counter << "; " << last_delta << std::endl;
                }
                return delta_p < 0.01 or counter < 1;
            }
        }
        double last_delta = 0;
        signed counter = 10000;
    };

    void evaluate(signed cycles) const {
        // std::vector<unsigned long> vertices_(network_.size());
        // for (auto [id, _] : network_)
        //     vertices_.push_back(id);

        Graph     g(network_.size());
        PosVector position(num_vertices(g));
        auto      wmap = get(boost::edge_weight, g);
        auto      eidx = get(boost::edge_index, g);

        for (size_t edge_idx = 0; auto [s, dd] : network_) {
            for (auto d : dd) {
                assert(d != s);
                assert(d < num_vertices(g));
                assert(s < num_vertices(g));
                auto [e, not_duplicate] = add_edge(s, d, g);

                if (not_duplicate) {
                    eidx[e] = edge_idx++; // required to map edges to [0, num_edges(g))
                    wmap[e] = 1.0;        // weight must all be non-negative
                }
            }
            position[s] = initial_positions_.at(s); // throws if not found.
        }
        auto position_map = make_iterator_property_map(position.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g));

        {
            // save graph-viz
            boost::dynamic_properties dp;
            dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, g));
            dp.property("pos", position_map);
            dp.property("edge_id", eidx);
            dp.property("weight", wmap);

        }

        kamada_kawai_done condition{ line_length, cycles};
        kamada_kawai_spring_layout(g, position_map, wmap, topo, boost::edge_length(line_length), std::ref(condition));
        save_positions(position);
    }
};

int main() {
    ExampleSpherical p(1);
    p.load_and_validate();
    p.evaluate(10000);
}

The initial network looks like this:

The processed/kamada_kawai_spring_layouted network is as follows:

This is an excellent improvement. There may definitely be tweaks, further improvements, and efficiencies that could be implemented - and I would love to hear about them - but the question is answered. The Kudos goes to sehe, however.
